# How to capture a square size photo in android app

Tags: java, android, camera, size, photo

I'm now developing an android app. In this app, user can take a photo and then upload it. But in the user interface, I want the photo be square size and also be displayed as square size. The following is my camerapreview code, I don't know where to add size parameters:

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = "CameraPreview";
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    private Uri outputMediaFileUri;
    private String outputMediaFileType;
    public File pic;
    public Uri uri;


    public CameraPreview(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
    }

    private static Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "camera is not available");
        }
        return c;
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mHolder.removeCallback(this);
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        int rotation = getDisplayOrientation();
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    }




    private File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), TAG);
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "prescription" + ".jpg");
            outputMediaFileType = "image/*";
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        outputMediaFileUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
        return mediaFile;
    }

    public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri() {
        return outputMediaFileUri;
    }

    public String getOutputMediaFileType() {
        return outputMediaFileType;
    }


    public void takePicture() {
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
                Log.i("camera", "file done");
                if (pictureFile == null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions");
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    Log.i("camera", "do outputstream");
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                    Log.i("camera", "after outputstream");
                    s = getOutputMediaFileUri().toString();
                    fos.write(data);
                    fos.close();



                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

    }



    public int getDisplayOrientation() {
        Display display = ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        int rotation = display.getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degrees = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degrees = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degrees = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degrees = 270;
                break;
        }

        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo camInfo =
                new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, camInfo);

        int result = (camInfo.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        return result;
    }

}
```

If I want to make sure the size of the photo and the camera preview are square size, where should I modify? Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

I use Picasso to work with images, it is very effective.

implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

```
Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
Picasso.get()
    .load(url)
    .resize(50, 50)//resize image
    .centerCrop()
    .into(imageView)
```

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Regards!